# best tool for rendering short items of text in wxPython and Kivi

Tags: kivy, restructuredtext, wxpython

I have a multi-platform app running on desktop (wxPython) and mobile (kivy). In it I want to render small areas of variable text in a window in the app. The text will depend on the state of the app. I am happy to use rtf, html or reStructuredText. I need to use the same source for the text on each platform.

A typical example of  a text snippet would be:

```
Heading
=======

1. With 24 widgets pull a **long** one;
2. with fewer, push a **wide** one.
```

Which would render as:

---

## Heading

1. With 24 widgets pull a **long** one;
2. with fewer, push a **wide** one.

---

My question is: which format should I use?

My preference would be reStructuredText. There appears to be a [kivy widget](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.rst.html) to support this but nothing in wxPython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the [docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/api/publisher.html) package.

This will take reStructuredText and output it as html. I can then use the wxPython wx.html control to display the output.

```
import wx
import wx.html as wxhtml
from docutils.core import publish_string



class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()

        input_string = ("Heading\n"
                        "=======\n"
                        "\n"
                        "1. With 24 widgets pull a **long** one;\n"
                        "2. with fewer, push a **wide** one.\n")
        self.display_rst(input_string)

    def display_rst(self, rst):
        html = publish_string(rst, writer_name='html')
        self.panel.html.SetPage(html)

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        display_style = wx.VSCROLL|wx.HSCROLL|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.BORDER_SIMPLE
        self.html = wxhtml.HtmlWindow(self, -1, size=(300, 200),
                                    style=display_style)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.html)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SCREEN_APP = wx.App()
    MAIN_FRAME = MainFrame(None, title="Display HTML")
    SCREEN_APP.MainLoop()
```